# Joining table to other table using either one of two columns

Tags: c#, mysql, join

I'm currently writing a program in C# and I want to load friendships from the database based on the id passed as function parameter.

I got 2 tables (I only display the important columns).

Table 1: players

```
+----------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                   | int(11)             | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username             | varchar(15)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Table 2: messenger_friends

```
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| user_one_id | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| user_two_id | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The thing is, my idea was the following: in messenger_friends, save one line for a friendship. I know I can save 2 for one friendship but it would mean more storage as 500 friendships would become 1000 records. Now, in my application I have to JOIN `messenger_friends` to `players`. I got this function:

```
public async Task<IReadOnlyList<MessengerFriend>> GetFriends(int playerId)
```

In here, I need to get all records from `messenger_friends` where EITHER `user_one_id` OR `user_two_id` is `playerId`. Then in the same query, I want to join it to players. I know I can get the records this way:

```
SELECT * FROM messenger_friends WHERE user_one_id = {playerId} OR user_two_id = {playerId}
```

But I'm not sure how to join it to the `players` table as I need to join EITHER `user_one_id` OR `user_two_id` with `players.id`

Comment: `JOIN messenger_friends f ON p.id in (f.user_one_id, user_two_id)`

Comment: `JOIN table ON id IN (fk1, fk2)` is a great idea, I didn't know it worked. You should post it as answer @juergend `f.user_two_id` by the way

Comment: You wrote *it would mean more storage as 500 friendships would become 1000 records*.  This is, with respect, a poor reason to de-optimize (denormalize) your data. If you have a choice don't design your data with extra columns where extra rows meet the need. Read about normalization.

Comment: @O.Jones so you say it'd be neater/better to store it as `user_id` and `friend_id` rather than how I want to do it?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It's a more flexible approach, and as you have discovered, leads to simpler and clearer queries.

Comment: @O.Jones Okay so I should go with that and just use 2 rows per friendship like I've done before?

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood you. Your friends table contains reciprocal relationships. Never Mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM players p
JOIN messenger_friends f ON p.id in (f.user_one_id, f.user_two_id)
WHERE p.id = {playerId}
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM players p
JOIN messenger_friends f ON p.id = f.user_one_id
                         OR P.id = f.user_two_id
WHERE p.id = {playerId}
```

Comment: I see you updated your answer, this however doesn't work as `= {playerId}` will link your own ID to players instead of the ID of your friend. I was able to get it to work with `!=` though.

Comment: Thanks for the query though, I thought the OR maybe wouldn't work in the JOIN. (was unable to edit comment).